# What is the use of HeaderText in HyerLinkField

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

What is the use of `HeaderText` property in a `HyperLinkField`?

Example:

```
<HyperLinkField DataTextField ="nam" DataNavigateUrlFields ="nam" DataNavigateUrlFormatString ="default2.aspx ? nam={1}" HeaderText = "nam" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The [HeaderText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.headertext.aspx) property holds the text that will be displayed in the column header for this [HyperLinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx).

Comment: is it possible that we have different column name in database and we can show different column name in grid view

Comment: @user635545, yes, it's possible. You can set `HeaderText` to any value that suits you.